# How to make flex-wrap balance its wrapped items?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am making a responsive layout, and on smaller screens a sidebar `<ul>` is turning into a `display: flex` with `flex-wrap: wrap` and the items styled with `flex-grow: 1`. This looks fine most of the time:

[image: Navigation menu with balanced wrapping]

However, this looks pretty bad when only a couple of items overflow, such as on a slightly larger screen:

[image: Navigation menu with the wrapping unbalanced]

Is there any way to get `flex-box` to attempt to wrap things based on having a balanced total item width per row? For example, in the second example, it would make much more sense for "People" (and maybe "Protocols" as well) to flow to the second line.

Or, is there is an alternate approach I should be taking to lay this menu out?

[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/kcLnzvx4/1/)

Comment: No...this is not possible without media queries. Flexbox/CSS doesn't know nor can it detect wrapping/overflow.

Comment: @ændrük Sort of, in the top/accepted answer is "you can't with the current flexbox spec."

Answer (score 3):

You could add a media query to change the behaviour in smaller viewports.

For example:

```css
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  nav li {
    min-width: 25%;
  }
}
```

That way, at least you won't have more than 4 items per row on a small screen.

Comment: That's an *okay* solution, although I'd rather the items be able to fit on a single line if they're small enough, as they are on larger tablets which are narrow enough to trigger the mobile layout (which I currently have at `max-width:800px`). Also there's other menus that have more items than this, with much more heterogeneous label lengths. So, I'll keep this in mind as a potential fix but I'm hoping to find something a bit more general. Thanks!